# Firebase functions.httpsCallable(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to use a function I made. So in my client I am doing this:

```js
const functions = firebase.app().functions("europe-west1");

        functions.httpsCallable('getSelf').then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            //stuff
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            switch (e.code) {
                //stuff
            }
        })
```

and basically I get the error that `functions.httpsCallable(...).then is not a function`. I dont really get it and I do not find any documentation how to make a function call on the client on a different version.

This is my serverside

```js
// Gets things like adminlevel, profilepic etc
exports.getSelf = functions.region("europe-west1").https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // Checking that the user is authenticated.
  if (!context.auth) 
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthorized', 'The function must be called ' +
        'while authenticated.');

  return db.collection("userInformation").doc(context.auth.uid).then(user => {
    if(!user)
      new functions.https.HttpsError('not-found', 'The user was not found');
    //returns needing values
    return {
      profilePicture: user.profilePicture,
      adminLevel: user.adminLevel,
      stripeAccountId: user.stripeAccountId,
      stripeCustomerId: user.stripeCustomerId,
      type: user.type
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HttpsCallable is itself a function that can be called with parameters, you need to add another `()` in there:

```
const getSelf = functions.httpsCallable('getSelf');
getSelf({}).then(...);
```

Comment: So that fixed my "not a function" error. Now I get an internal error.

Comment: Looks like `return db.collection("userInformation").doc(context.auth.uid)` needs to be `return db.collection("userInformation").doc(context.auth.uid).get()` as well.